# React redux bindActionCreators usage

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

i have a file inside action directory which is root.js.
Root.js will compile all the others action inside, and i bind it with bindActionCreators

```
export const all = (store) => {
    AUTH: bindActionCreators(AUTH.actions, store.dispatch),
    ....: .....
}
```

From what i learned, bindActionCreators is for the purpose of auto dispatching the action.
If that is the case, then how do i access it from smart component?

I see things like dispatch(action). But since now i already bind it globally, i dont think that i would need to specify dispatch anymore. How do i do it, or is there any part that i misunderstood?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bindActionCreators` - will create an object of actions each wrapped with the dispatch.
It's good for passing them as refs to non-connected components that should not know anything about `redux` or `dispatch`.
Quote from the [DOCS](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/bindActionCreators.html#bindactioncreatorsactioncreators-dispatch):

> The only use case for bindActionCreators is when you want to pass some
>   action creators down to a component that isn't aware of Redux, and you
>   don't want to pass dispatch or the Redux store to it.

So if you want that connected component to pass action creators to a dumb component, you can set an object via `bindActionCreators` and pass it with props to the dumb component.
Example:

```
const myActionCreators = bindActionCreators(Auth.myActions, dispatch)
<DumbComponent {...myActionCreators} />
```

Comment: does that mean that i no longer need to  specify mapDispatchToProps?

Comment: do i need to mapStateToProps? or it is already automatically hooked to the store via connect? sorry for asking.. cause i am still catching the concept of react redux

Comment: you return `bindActionCreators` from `mapDispatchToProps` like `function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch)
}
`

Comment: hm..
One more question. 
does that mean by just specifying function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) { return bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch) }, i can access this.props.Auth.actionName() from my dumb component that is connected to this store?

Comment: i'm sorry i miss-read your question i thought you were asking about mapDispatchToProps as well as bindActionCreators. i will update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The recommended approach is to have each connected component file import the action creators it needs, and use the "object shorthand" supported by `connect`:

```
import {addTodo, toggleTodo} from "./todoActions";

const actions = {addTodo, toggleTodo};

export default connect(null, actions)(TodoList);
// each TodoList instance now has this.props.addTodo and
// this.props.toggleTodo, which will dispatch actions when called.
```

Comment: Brilliant.
This is what i am looking for..

I think that this approach is more readable and easier to maintain, rather than having each smart component perform dispatch on their own

Comment: but i cannot get it to work..
I agree with this workflow though

Comment: Can you clarify what "doesn't work"?  Are you actually rendering the _connected_ version of the component?

Comment: Sorry, get it to work now with const actions = {
 "loginDefault" : AUTH_ACTIONS.actions.loginDefault
}